# How to stream from a Mobile phone using PubNub Web RTC in Ionic?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, video-streaming, webrtc, pubnub

I am using **Ionic Framework** to develop an android app, which needs to stream video from a mobile phone to web. I tried **PubNub Web RTC** and I was able to stream video from web browser to app. But I cannot do it vice versa. When I inspected Ionic App it shows the following Error on webrtc.js :

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'addStream' on 'RTCPeerConnection': The 1st argument provided is either null, or an invalid MediaStream object.